# Can I have a 'protected' member in a parent class and inherit it in a child class?

Tags: c#, modifier

I have 3 kinds of users like admin, customer, and supplier, which are all planned to be inherited from the `User` class. Can I use `protected` for `username` and `password` in the `User` class and inherit them in child classes? All tutorials seem to use `private`, is there any special reason for that?

Comment: You should read the documentation about access modifiers...

Comment: You can. Use case depends on your needs. Check out C# tutorials about modifiers

Comment: _"all tutorials seems using private"_ i guess you confuse the (backing) fields of the properties with the properties itself. The properties are normally not private but the fields.

Comment: Yes.  In fact this is the only purpose of protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use protected for username and password in user class

Yes

Whether you should is another question. If they are fields, they personally I'd say: keep the field `private` and add a `protected` *property* - or just simply:

```
protected string UserName {get;set;}
```

or maybe:

```
protected string UserName {get;private set;}
```

if only the base class should be able to set it, or

```
protected string UserName {get;}
```

if only the base class should be able to set it *and only in the constructor*

Side note: *any* discussion of storing a password - even in memory - makes me nervous.

Comment: Given the nature of the question, consider that the OP might think that "protected" means that the password is protected :)

Comment: @HansPassant don't go there... please :)